# Per-folder settings in PCManFM?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, pcmanfm

Each folder in PCManFM uses global settings. Is there any option to save settings such as file sorting and view mode in PCManFM for a specific folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can save a folder's settings by opening the folder, and choosing **View->Preserve This Folder's Settings**.
[image]

The settings are going to be saved in `~/.config/libfm/dir-settings.conf` or `~/.config/pcmanfm/dir-settings.conf`.

Comment: When I was checking the answer, I had to change the setting back to my original setting for all the other folders.  The selected folder retained the selected settings.

Comment: @Rex you have to restart PCManFM, then will be everything fine.

Comment: You are correct Mike.  I checked it again and that works for me as well.

Comment: @MichalH, By any chance, is it possible to apply View settings to all folders? Somehow it's always resets to the default one (`Ctrl-1`) for me...

Comment: @AS: Edit -> Preferences -> Default View (down at bottom)